# Sorting date inside of files (Python)

Tags: python

I have a txt file with names and dates like this

name0 - 05/09/2020

name1 - 14/10/2020

name2 - 02/11/2020

How can I sort the text file by date? so that the file will end up like this

name2 - 02/11/2020

name1 - 14/10/2020

name0 - 05/09/2020

(I use dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples.  It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem. 
 [https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to do this, along with the builtin reading functionality:

```
from datetime import datetime

# Read in the file
with open("file.txt", "r") as infile:
    contents = infile.readlines()
contents = [c.strip() for c in contents]

# Grab the dates
dates = [line.split("-")[1].strip() for line in contents]
dates = [datetime.strptime(d, "%d/%m/%Y") for d in dates]

# Zip contents and dates together
zipped = list(zip(contents, dates))
# Sort them
sorted_zipped = sorted(zipped, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
# Unzip them and grab the sorted contents
sorted_contents = next(zip(*sorted_zipped))

# Write the sorted contents back out
with open("outfile.txt", "w") as out:
    out.write("\n".join(sorted_contents))
```

Comment: I get this error message referring to the line 'sorted_contents = zip(*sorted_zipped)[0]'

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Whoops - gotta either convert back to a list or use `next`. To save memory, I'd use `next(zip(*sorted_zipped)))`. I'll change it in the answer, as well

Comment: Also had to make a few other changes to make this work, as it was untested. Added a line to strip out the newline characters from `contents`, included `reverse=True` in the call to `sorted`, and made the `next` change mentioned above.

Comment: Ah okay thank you! I am not at all familair with zipping this is basically witch craft for me haha. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Haha yes zipping can be very confusing - here's a good [resource on zip](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/). It's seriously worth your time, you'll end up using it more than you think, and it includes how to "Unzip" (which is what I'm doing the second time I call zip)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey I still have an issue with the code, when assigning the two dates variables since I use it in async it goes wrong there.
I get a unconverted data remains error message.
Do you think the is anything I can do about this?

Comment: Sorry what part are you doing via async? I'm not sure that's what the problem is - "unconverted data remains" usually indicates that the first argument to `strptime` doesn't match the described formatting. Are you positive that all of the txt files have the described format? You can take a look at the `dateutil` library, it has a `parser` module and the `parse` function is *very* powerful and *very* flexible

Answer (score 0):

First, read the file with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("name_of_file.csv",sep="-",names=["names","dates"])
```

I noticed that your example data has a "space" between the separator "-", so when you read the first line, the date value would be  `05/09/2020` instead of `05/09/2020`. So to fix this, you only have to do this previus line:

```
df.dates = df.dates.apply(lambda x: x[1:]
```

Second, we have to give format to date:

```
df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates,format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Then, we have to sort descending

```
df = df.sort_values(by='dates',ascending=False)
```

Finally, if you want to save your file just do this:

```
df.to_csv("data_sorted.txt",sep="-",index=False)
```