# How to sort data by mm/yyyy?

Tags: python

Hello I am new to python, if I have a txt.file like so

```
23/3/2020 12
7/7/2020 15
25/1/2020 16
14/2/2020 12
12/3/2020 19
1/11/2020 11
16/6/2020 20
14/3/2020 13
13/11/2020 20
```

(all of them are strings)and I want to turn it into a dict() with mm/yyyy as the key and the sum of the numbers on the same month as value, what should I do?

Comment: Could you more clearly specify what the format of the text file is? Are there line breaks? Wrap the text file format in ``` for clarity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting date inside of files (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64668250/sorting-date-inside-of-files-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet takes in the file, reads in one line at a time, and maintains counters for each `month/year` combination seen so far:

```py
month_counters = {}

with open('test.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        [date, num] = line.split()
        month_and_year = date[date.index("/") + 1:]
        if month_and_year in month_counters:
            month_counters[month_and_year] += int(num)
        else:
            month_counters[month_and_year] = int(num)

print(month_counters)
```

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend just using Python's builtin [datetime parsing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and [collections.counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this. Essentially, parse the dates and add the count to the counter.

```
from collections import Counter
from datetime import datetime

counts = Counter()

with open(path) as f:
    for date, count in map(str.split, f):        
        date = datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y')
        counts[date.month, date.year] += int(count)

counts
```

The result is a dict with month-year tuples and totals:

```
Counter({(3, 2020): 44,
         (7, 2020): 15,
         (1, 2020): 16,
         (2, 2020): 12,
         (11, 2020): 31,
         (6, 2020): 20})
```